# How to use Spock to test a Grails service method that uses a static method from a Domain Class?

Tags: grails, spock

So, I am trying to test the following Grails service implementation:

```
class BookService {
    def searchBooks(String search) {
        if (!search) {
            return []
        }
        Book.searchBooks(search)
    }
}
```

It uses a method defined in the Book domain class:

```
class Book {
    String title
    static def searchBooks(String search) {
        Book.findByTitleLike(search)
    }
}
```

So, this is the test code I've been trying:

```
@TestFor(BookService)
@Mock(Book)
class BookServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "should search books"() {
        setup:
        new Book(title: 'The Stand').save()
        new Book(title: 'Under the Dome').save()
        new Book(title: 'Bag of Bones').save()
        when:
        service.searchBooks('ones')
        then:
        1 * Book.searchBooks()
    }
}
```

But, it always fails with:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * Book.searchBooks()   (0 invocations)
```

I've debugged the code running in an IDE and the method seems to be indeed executed, but Spock does not register the execution.

What am I missing?
Is there something else I have to do to mock the domain class method?

[Here is a sample project with the code](http://ge.tt/3Mw2Dkm/v/0?c).

Comment: I am skeptical you cannot verify static methods in domain class. The caveat here is, if you use [GroovyMock](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#mocking-all-instances-of-a-type) to verify static method, you will loose the domain class behavior but the test would pass. Although, you can give it a try. Also try with [GroovySpy](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#mocking-static-methods).

Comment: @dmahapatro Thanks, man! Yeah, I ended up using GroovyMock in the service test, verifying that the method is called. Then, the behavior of the domain class method I verify in the domain class own test. I guess that makes sense. Thank you. :)